# Vuetify default styles issue in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

my code is

```
<div class="cd-page__details-wrapper">
  <v-text-field
    label="Outlined"
    placeholder="Outlined"
    outlined
  ></v-text-field>
</div>
```

But I've got somthing horrible

[image: printscreen of component]

My nuxt.config.js

```js
buildModules: [
  '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
  '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
],
```

Comment: You don't need the `dotenv` module, it's already baked in now. Also, what is horrible here? It does have an accessibility outline here, nothing wrong. You want to edit it? Check the CSS of the given element and overwrite it if needed. But don't remove it, people do need that one.

Comment: Have you tried without `cd-page__details-wrapper` ?

Comment: @kissu, IVO GELOV, thanks for help, problem has been solved by adding v-app

Answer (score 1):

OP's issue was solved by adding `v-app` to the main `div` like that

```html
<div class="v-app">
  <v-text-field
    label="Outlined"
    placeholder="Outlined"
    outlined
  ></v-text-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was getting some missing CSS of my Vuetify components in the production build, the problem was with the `nuxt-purgecss` module, after removing it from the `modules` key in `nuxt.config.ts` and rebuilding again, it worked.

But now there is a problem with the unpurged CSS (as pointed out by kissu), so I opened a issue in the repo of the `nuxt-purgecss` module.

Issue: [Vuetify 3 styles missing in production build](https://github.com/Developmint/nuxt-purgecss/issues/187)

Comment: Be mindful of your unpurged CSS now tho!